# Let [shellscript] burn in [shell]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

As a frequent visitor to the [bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bash) and [awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/awk) tags, I can't help but notice a new kid on the block:

[shellscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shellscript) (84 questions tagged at time of writing)

> A shell script is a computer program designed to be run by the Unix shell, a command line interpreter.

Hmm, sounds a bit like [shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shell) (35,305 questions tagged)

> The term 'shell' refers to a general class of text-based command interpreters most often associated with the Unix & Linux operating systems.

The difference being that the latter rightly acknowledges that there are a whole bunch of different shells, each with their own characteristics.

There is no such thing as *shellscript* and this new tag adds no value. Furthermore, we should be encouraging users to be specific about the shell they're using, rather than referring to some generic pseudo-language. If they mean POSIX [sh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sh), then there's already a tag for that.

Please can we get rid of it?

I'm not necessarily proposing that we simply re-tag questions to [shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shell), as many of the questions already specify a specific shell, e.g. bash, ksh, sh, etc. In this case, the tag should just be removed.

Comment: Burn it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5dJznTAwLSY

Comment: New kid on the chopping block, more like.

Comment: I like the title, I like @ssube's comment, I like Unix, I like shells... This is a good question.

Comment: The [tag:shellscript] tag should, IMNSHO, be burninated, if only because it was created (first used) on 2015-04-04 and the site survived 6 years and more without it.

Comment: I've updated the [tag:shellscript] wiki description to make it clear it should not be used (not that doing so will stop it being (mis)used).  Time to go on the editing binge.  Someone got themselves a 'taxidermist' badge out of it, of course.

Comment: And, while we're at it, [tag:bash-scripting] has rather limited benefit...it should go too!  _[...time passes...]_ And [tag:bash-scripting] passes out of use too.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

With some help from [Mat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/635608/mat), all the questions that were tagged [shellscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shellscript) now have more appropriate tags.

Thanks, Mat.

Oh, and the nine questions that used to be tagged [bash-scripting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bash-scripting) are also no longer tagged like that — two tags burninated for the price of one.

Comment: There's a 2x1 deal? *hurries to write meta Q*

Comment: Grrr…just out of cussedness, I went to check that there were still zero questions tagged [tag:shellscript].  There was a new one — it has been untagged and a comment left suggesting that the OP pays attention to what the tag wikis say.

Answer (score 5):

Yet another case where the tag synonyms would have been helpful: [shellscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shellscript) was suggested as synonym by Gilles [a couple of weeks ago](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms?filter=suggested&tab=newest). To the date, it just had one vote (it needs 4 to be accepted), as can be seen in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/shell/synonyms.

We really have to make some improvement in the voting tag synonyms! [What about making a badge for it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/197656/209901)

Comment: Oddly, the fact that a tag has been suggested as a synonym for something else doesn't show on the synonym's tag page, only on the master's. That is, if you'd looked at [shellscript], there is no mention that it has been proposed as a synonym of [shell].

Comment: And the synonym has been approved. Thanks for bringing this up...I rarely visit tag pages so I never would have seen the suggestion otherwise.

Answer (score -14):

The difference is there in the tag, no? A shell script is thing that is interpreted by the shell.

Your premise is a bit like saying there is no such thing as source code, and what people should be refering to is compilers.

Comment: I take your point but the issue is that the term _shell script_, like shell, encompasses many different things. The tag is completely ambiguous. We don't (and shouldn't) have a _bash script_ tag to distinguish between scripts written in bash and bash itself, so why should we make this distinction in the more general case? Do you know of any questions that benefit from the inclusion of this tag, that wouldn't be better served by a more specific one based on the language they are referring to?

Comment: I would also suggest that [tag:shellscript] is unnecessarily specific to Unix. There are other operating systems which have a shell, whether they call it that or not, and which have scripting languages to address the shell.

Comment: Since you mentioned it, [tag:source-code] is an awful tag, too.

Comment: Yes [source-code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/source-code) should also be burned to the ground.  I don't know whay it hasn't since it has `PLEASE DON'T USE THIS TAG!` right at the start.

Comment: Wait. What? there is a source-code tag?  That has to go surely.

Comment: Sadly, there are 1800+ questions with the [tag:source-code].  The MSE question [Do we really need a `source-code` tag](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/197865/do-we-really-need-a-source-code-tag) is referenced in the wiki.

Comment: @yellowantphil, I agree, but would add that there's a thin line between a shell script in a file, and a complex pipe or loop command in one go at the prompt.  (It's pretty much a mathematical line: zero-width.  If you want to save a complex one-liner, you put it in a file.)  And what's the line between a pipe or loop at a prompt, and, say, 'ls'?  No line there, either.  So in addition to brevity, there's semantic reason to leave "-script" off of these tags.