# Let's burn the [source-code]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

Looking at the comments to [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/292056) on [Let [shellscript] burn in [shell]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/292023) I found out that we have a [source-code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/source-code) tag.  When you go to the tag it has in the excerpt:

> PLEASE DON'T USE THIS TAG! It is too broad, so it is not very useful. Please see: [Do we really need a [source-code] tag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/197865/do-we-really-need-a-source-code-tag)

As the link suggest and as most people would probably agree [source-code] is a fairly redundant and useless tag.  Is there any reason to keep this tag around?

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Zm85C.png

Comment: @JonH Sadly, not yet. Operative word here, hopefully, being 'yet'.

Comment: We need a more interesting title here! Something like, *To hell with the [source-code]*

Comment: @BhargavRao: I'd suggest something about commenting it out, or possibly refactoring.

Comment: It ([tag:source-code]) should go.  Sadly, there are 1800+ questions with the tag.  That makes it too large for a manual process unless we organize a hit-squad to coordinate the work.  How do we get Stack Overflow staff (or perhaps moderators) to trigger the tools that can do the burnination automatically?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I seldom of doing it that way, since that tag seems to attract closeable questions.

Comment: We really need something like [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151920/add-the-ability-to-lock-tags) implemented for a coordinated manual removal, @JonathanLeffler (though this one isn't growing very fast). Nuking from orbit is problematic like Braiam said.

Comment: Eh. There's [[source](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/source)] too... even worse.

Comment: @BhargavRao is *let's burn the [source-code]* good enough ?

Comment: @BhargavRao What about _rm -rf ./source-code/*_?

Comment: I used up all my downvotes on [source-code] for the day. The same thing can be done for [\[source\]](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=[source]%20answers%3a0%20score%3a0). If the question is bad, one downvote will let it be roomba'd at the end of the day. If it is good, edit the question.

Comment: I've removed the tags [tag:source] and [tag:source-code] from the dozen questions tagged with both.  A minute drop in the bucket, but every little bit helps.  (I also retagged the question that had the [tag:ffmpag] tag with the [tag:ffmpeg] tag.  Another tag that won't be bothering us for long.  It's weird where cleanups lead you.)

Comment: There is a potential use for this tag: we could make it automatically dump the question in the low quality queue, then untag itself. :)

Comment: @reirab that should be the default behavior for all meta tags. :)

Comment: I'm just grateful there isn't a `codes` tag ... yet

Comment: @Synesso C'mon we all need a `[gimmetehcodez]` tag. It will help us cv them faster!

Comment: @BhargavRao There [*was*](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/116770/234299) a `plz-send-teh-codez` tag, along with other similar variations. The use of such tags is [highly discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19780#19780).

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot Yeah I knew that! That comment was sarcastic by nature. If ya didn't get it. :D ... Actually there was a mention about [gimmetehcodez] tag too, but I'm not getting the rite link. :D

Comment: @JonathanLeffler By the way, we **have** organized a hit-squad to coordinate the work. See my answer.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

## Burnination Status Wiki

[The SO Close Vote Reviewers chatroom](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/24361107#24361107) has agreed to take [source-code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/source-code) <del>under our wing</del> in our claws.

## Currently there are <del>1587</del> **0** remaining questions with this tag. Good job everyone for burninating!!

#### Blacklist log:

Please add questions here that have this tag, so we can prove that it keeps popping back up and needs to be blacklisted.

- <s>https://stackoverflow.com/q/32300770/</s>
- <s>https://stackoverflow.com/q/35670124/</s>
- <s>https://stackoverflow.com/q/35343497/</s>
- <s>https://stackoverflow.com/q/36592594/</s>

#### Closing Status:

Every single question with this tag is now gone!

[image: Slammed the door]

Comment: Note: Roomba won't remove questions closed as duplicates. Those either need to be voted for deletion or have the tags edited.

Comment: @durron597 Thanks. I must have been reading to fast I agree that it would these tags would be much more useful than simply saying source-code. I will join the battle.

Comment: Found the 'readability' and 'code-readability' tags (not superior). Take the coding-style and code-quality tags. Coding-style is at least pretty much the same as 'readability' or 'code-readability' - at very least its simonious in majority of circumstances, and where does 'readability' fit when 'code-readability' doesnt? surely not on its own, and there are 'formatting', 'format' and other tags that prob suit better when talking about any data readability. At the very least 'readablity' can be marked redundant (and maybe is in another topic, but in tag description)

Comment: And when does 'code-formatting' not be 'coding-style' or 'code-readability', or even just be solved by combination tags including 'code-quality', 'naming-conventions', 'code-structure' or other related tags?

Comment: They keep [coming back](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/32360199/revisions) :(

Comment: @paulrob you need to ask a new meta question asking for the blacklisting

Answer (score -21):

Okay, I'm the one that will say it, what about questions about where to find source code?

Example: [Where to find Java JDK Source Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2896727/where-to-find-java-jdk-source-code)

Or about impact of whitespace in source code?

Example: [Can empty lines between code lines decrease the performance of program in asp.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29768834/gap-between-the-coding-lines-can-decrease-the-performance-of-program-in-asp-net)

Or general questions about source code, without any specification on what language?

Example: [Code snippet management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23593291/code-snippet-management)

I totally agree that in 90% of the cases this tag is useless and I've been removing them when I have some time, but in some cases, this actually is a useful tag.

Comment: 1. [java-sdk]; 2. [asp.net]; 3. should be closed. There is no need for the tag.

Comment: Third one is Off Topic -> Recommendation. And I wouldn't say the others _need_ the [tag:source-code] tag.

Comment: Why did you filled up review queues with `Don't use the tag "source-code"`? It's totally useless, read from [Help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit): Editing a post also bumps the question to the top of the homepage. Please be mindful of this and make your edits count, so that the new attention is brought to something substantial.

Comment: When you edit posts, fix every possible thing. You can look at the second example to see what you missed.

Comment: The first one must be closed. It is a hidden recommendation request and if you don't read it as such a request it is still too broad/unclear, because to answer it correctly one must know what linux OP talks about.