# Is it acceptable to put in tag Wiki "don't use this tag unless you have a really good reason"?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-wiki

I staggered across the [vowel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vowel) tag. The top tags associated with [vowel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vowel) are: [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python), [string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/string), [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java), [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex), [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php), and [count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/count). Clearly, it has no specific application in programming.

The vast majority of the questions are similar to "How to tell if a character is a vowel", "How to split a string at vowels", "Get number of vowels in a string", and so on. These sorts of questions are most related to string and array operations, and have nothing to do with the actual concept of a vowel. Of course, there are a couple of good questions having to do with vowels such as [Playing around with Devanagari characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6805311/playing-around-with-devanagari-characters) and [Counting Syllables In A Word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9096228/counting-syllables-in-a-word), but these are exceptions.

Since this tag isn't really doing *harm*, it is [not worth burninating](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate/239191#239191) (not to mention burninating would be a bunch of [busy work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate/239191#239191)). Since it is just being used as a filler tag across such a scope of programming problems and languages, it is pointless and shouldn't exist.

To prevent it from being used, would it be acceptable for me to edit the tag's wiki, saying something like:

> This tag has an ambiguous meaning in the scope of programming. Please do not use the [vowel] tag unless your question specifically deals with an aspect of language.

?

Comment: @durron597 Thanks for showing me that.

Comment: There are lots of tags with wikis like that... however, I *do* think vowel is worth burninating.

Comment: @Will: I think you mean BRN TH VWL! With which I fully agree.

Comment: This question isn't about "BRN TH VWL"!! It was supposed to be more generalized, but now it has descended into a bunch of joke comments ;)

Comment: I don't see why a tag topic would need to have a specific application. Hey, that it is used with so many languages shows that is has a very broad application in programming!

Comment: @Bergi the point of this post is not that tags _must_ be specific, it is that they add information to the question. [tag:vowel] has become so woolly and pointless (since it doesn't really describe at all what the heart of the question is) that it should not be used except in a few specific cases.

Comment: burn the vowel ! One less to buy on wheel of fortune!

Comment: @bcdan What few specific cases? I can't think of a single reason or example to justify the existence of a 'vowel' tag.

Answer (score 15):

For what it's worth, I burninated [vowel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vowel) and it will disappear in a few hours at the next cleanup.

Generally speaking though, editing tags during cleanup periods is okay, as we've done in the case of [source-code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/source-code).

Comment: Surely you mean: *Fr wht t's wrth,  brnntd vwl nd wll dsppr n fw hrs t th nxt clnp*?

Comment: @Angew nothing to see here, move along ;)

Answer (score 1):

From what I gather, it is perfectly acceptable to put "Do not use this tag" in a tag wiki, if the tag is silly, ambiguous, does not add anything to questions, or otherwise *should* be burninated.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that any tag where the warning is necessary has nominated itself for burnination.  Maybe we should turn this into a feature request?

Comment: Well, it sounds like durron already cleaned up all of them

Comment: This already happens. See [tag:source-code] and [associated meta post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/298903/1768232)