# Why was this question undeleted?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, opinion-based, undeleted-questions

[Storing installation files in Version Control to automate dev machine setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26149344/1768232)

This question [was deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/26149344/revisions) as part of the [source-code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/source-code) [cleanup](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/298903/1768232). It now has two reopen votes (at the time of this question being written).

I don't understand why this question is being reopened. It is a blatantly opinion based question and doesn't have one answer. The solution to it is basically a tool recommendation.

It only has 80 views at the time of the MSO post being written. I don't understand why it was undeleted, though I could be persuaded on that point... but **certainly** not on reopening it!

It has too few views for a historical lock, so that seems wrong as well. Can we delete it again please?

Comment: Are you sure it was deleted it has an upvoted accepted answer?

Comment: @NathanOliver I deleted it, along with two others. See the [edit history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/26149344/revisions)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It was undeleted because it was flagged for undeletion; and the undeletion flag reason resonated with the moderator who undeleted it.

I agree with it being undeleted.

It was originally closed for being 'primarily opinion based', even though there was only one sentence that made it that.

It was deleted presumably for the same reason.

I edited the question, removed the opinion portion, and re-opened it.

If you find yourself deleting questions with great answers, you're going to have to justify why.  In this case, the justification doesn't match the extraordinarily low amount of effort needed to fix the issue.

Comment: When I got to the question, it asked "should I store executables in version control?" (not how do I do it?) and its score was -3. The only answer was a tool recommendation. You have changed my mind, I didn't see a valuable question hidden inside it until your edits.