# What do the statistics for a community wiki represent?

Tags: support, community-wiki

[This community wiki answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/292086/lets-burn-the-source-code/298903#298903) has the following statistics:

[image: For Example: In this image]

What do the statistics 8 users and 72% mean in the above image? Based on my understanding, 29 revisions have been made to that particular post. But I'm not able to get the other things.
And why is the username durron597 still there if the question has been made a community-wiki?

Comment: I *think* the user name indicates the person who originally created the post but I'm not sure. I don't know what the percentage means.

Comment: `Additionally, community wiki posts show the editor with the highest percentage of the remaining post in the current version in the author field.` http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit-community-wiki

Comment: And the 8 users means that 8 different users have contributed in editing the post.  So there should be 8 unique users in the revision history.

Comment: See [Why do Community Wiki posts show the user responsible for the largest % of edits instead of the posting user?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/158599/164403) on the Overmeta for the rationale behind this.

Comment: Changing to `29 revs, 8 users, <br/> 72% from durron597 ` would be much better.

Comment: Yes i  agree with falsarella. It will be helpful for newbie like me :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit-community-wiki) says the following:

> Additionally, community wiki posts show the editor with the highest percentage of the remaining post in the current version in the author field.

So here's the breakdown of what those numbers mean.

> 29 revs

This is the number of revisions the post has currently, similar to a normal non-wiki post.

> 8 users

This is the number of distinct authors that have contributed to the post. Only when a new author that hasn't edited the post before contributes will the number increase.

> 72% durron597

This is the the editor with the highest percentage of the remaining post in the current version. (That is a bit fuzzy to me, but you get the idea)

---

Now that I (durron597) have edited this post, it will have a **percentage** with gunr2171 (ties go to the original author). Note that [this answer was originally written by @rene, but @JasonMArcher did most of the revs so now it says his name.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/295218/1768232).  Furthermore, [the algorithm that computes this percentage can mess up sometimes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35972/diff-percentage-seems-a-bit-off).

Comment: If only we had the foresight to demonstrate with a community wiki.  And it would even make sense based on the comments.  It seems three different users explained one of the 3 statistics (you, me, and the OP).

Comment: @ryanyuyu, it's a CW now, edit in your percentage info in please

Comment: And now that this is a community wiki, I have contributed what small extra info I had in my answer.  How convenient.

Comment: Can we get a non-breaking-space between the ``%`` and the user name?