# What really happens when I edit a Community Wiki post?

Tags: support

I just earned the privilege of "Edit community wiki" (yay!) and the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit-community-wiki) offers some explanation, what can I do with this, and how it works. My question is actually answered there, as follows (*emphasis* mine):

> ### What happens when I edit a Community Wiki post?
>
> All edits are stored in a revision history for the post, along with the author of the revision. Additionally, community wiki posts show the editor *with the highest percentage of the remaining post* in the current version in the author field.

Can someone clarify what *[having] the highest percentage of the remaining post* means? I must admit that English is not my first language, but this wording does not make any sense to me. What does "remaining" refer to? Maybe the expression "amount of contribution" is actually missing here? If so, then how is contribution measured?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "remaining" part of the post is what's in the most recent revision.

When a post is edited, some stuff may be crossed out in red, and some stuff may be added in green. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/927358/revisions) for example. The way a contribution is calculated is:

- Add up all of the green characters an editor made.
- Subtract the number of those characters that were removed in red in other edits.

Here is another Meta post about this: [What do the statistics for a community wiki represent?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/299776)

Some details about the pitfalls of the algorithm can be found here: [Diff percentage seems a bit off](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/35972/323179)