# What should be done with this thoroughly off topic, highly voted question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

###<strike>https://stackoverflow.com/q/1473940/1768232</strike>

This question is:

- About as off topic as it's possible to be
- Has two tags that ought to be burninated, [legal](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/295117/1768232) and [source-code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/298903/1768232)

  - I can't think of *any* **good**, correct tags to replace it with
  - Leave it closed is not good enough, because of the burnination efforts in the above links
- Is too highly upvoted and has too much worth saving in the answers to be deleted (or is it?)
- Isn't controversial enough to be historically locked (or is it?) I would support that, but [I've been told in the past that it needs to be controversial](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/41570?m=24385444#24385444) for a historical lock.

  - Controversial being defined as a delete/undelete war or attracting bad answers.
- It should not be migrated to Programmers.SE because:

  - [It is not on topic there either](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1655/88986)
  - [It is too old to migrate anywhere](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/136543/200235)

What should be done here?

Comment: Migrate to programmers.se, or close it, that works too, I guess.

Comment: @DJDavid98 [Wrong.](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/1655/88986) [For lots of reasons](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/136543/200235)

Comment: @DJDavid98 ^^^ what durron597 wrote. Recommended reading: **[What goes on Programmers.SE? A guide for Stack Overflow](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7182/31260)**

Comment: First, I wouldn't call that "highly voted". Second, I don't see anything good about it worth sticking around. Every answer seems to be "hire a lawyer"

Comment: The fact that the question is from **2009** seems to have escaped everyone's notice.

Comment: @ChrisF It hasn't escaped mine, but tag burnination requires addressing even the questions from 2009.

Comment: @ChrisF I noticed that but not sure the difference it makes here. It isn't useful in any way that I saw.

Comment: 600 views in 5 years. Apparently nobody expects to look for questions like that at SO

Comment: It's almost 10 years old, but has less than 700 views. That's about 0.2 views per day over the life of the question. I suspect it will jump a little because of this Meta post, but be insignificant. Of those viewers, it has only gained 13 votes (12 up / 1 down) on the question and 2 favorites. Doesn't seem like a good historical lock candidate since it doesn't seem to be that useful.

Comment: @codeMagic (and durron597). It does make a difference. Firstly, a new question *could* be migrated if it was any good. Secondly Stack Overflow was different back then. This sort of question was allowed.

Comment: @ChrisF I mean as far as my comment on it not needing to stick around (should be eliminated). I understand it was acceptable then but it was just as unhelpful back then.

Comment: @DJDavid98 http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73382/please-stop-using-programmers-se-as-your-toilet-bowl

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Vote to delete. Given it's current vote count it'll take more than 3 votes, so if you want to speed up the process down-vote as well. This will reduce the number of delete votes that are required.

It doesn't have the high number of views that would warrant an historical lock.

That's it.

Comment: +1 It's already closed as off-topic and there's nothing useful in the answers other than "we can't help, get a lawyer", so I was about to write the same thing. I'll go downvote it now.

Comment: Status complete.

Comment: Are you sure it is okay to use down votes to decrease the amount of delete votes needed?  It goes against what Shog says [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307010/4342498)

Comment: @NathanOliver - Shog's answer was written a couple of months after I posted this, but if something's worth deleting then it needs to be deleted. A down-vote here or there isn't probably going to make much difference though.

Answer (score 6):

Historical locks are for questions of **extremely** high value.  A dozen votes, over the course of 6 years, and only a few hundred views, is not very much traffic at all, and is not in any way an indication of *extremely* high value.  It's at best, of moderate value.

Looking at the actual content though, the question is a legal question, not a programming question, and the only answers are "hire a lawyer".  This question doesn't need to exist to provide that information to people.

I see no reason to keep such a question around, it can just be deleted.  It certainly doesn't need a historical lock.

Comment: *" This question doesn't need to exist to provide that information to people."* unfortunately it somehow does because I've seen quite a few people asking questions and the answer is always "Hire a lawyer". So sad. But agreed it shouldn't exist here