# Let's merge the [specific-question] and [specific-answer] tags, create the opposite and make either one required when asking on meta

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags, meta

I like hanging out on meta to see discussions about Stack Overflow. [I even asked questions myself](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/2788131/d4v1d?tab=questions) in order to be more involved in the community.

However, I'm least interested in meta questions asking about specific Stack Overflow questions, I'm much more interested in questions about Stack Overflow as a whole. Therefore, I moved the tags [specific-question](/questions/tagged/specific-question) and [specific-answer](/questions/tagged/specific-answer) to my ignored tags list so I'm not bothered anymore by these questions.

That being said, I see [lots of questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22this%20question%22%20-%5Bspecific-question%5D) (3,484 as of now) that **should** include the [specific-question](/questions/tagged/specific-question) tag as they are asking about, well, a specific question asked on Stack Overflow but **they don't** (the same applies for [the 981, as of now, questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22this%20answer%22%20-%5Bspecific-answer%5D) that should include the [specific-answer](/questions/tagged/specific-answer) tag).

Couldn't we:

1. merge the tags [specific-answer](/questions/tagged/specific-answer) and [specific-questions](/questions/tagged/specific-questions) into one tag that would apply to both questions and answers (and event comments) such as `specific-post`;
2. make this newly created tag *required* in addition with an opposite *required* tag (that could be `general-post`) when asking question on meta.

Therefore, I would like to request a feature here: couldn't these suggestions be implemented to handle future MSO questions while I start doing the job of retagging already-posted questions?

Comment: What about *"An example of this broad topic that I want to discuss would be this question..."*? This is going to be very difficult to automate. We could perhaps encourage use of this tag by adding a second required tag, i.e. one of bug/discussion/support/feature request and one of specific question/[whatever the opposite is]

Comment: Also, sometimes it should be specific-answer, even if the question might be linked. And even if the OP asks about a specific question, the Q&A and the discussion might be llots more general.

Comment: Maybe a link to all tags should be included in the suggestions that appear when you first move the cursor to the tags box. I think it's not getting used because not only do people not know it exists but because 'discussion' seems sufficient.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: I agree this could be difficult to automate. That is why I have edited my question with your feature idea.

Comment: @D4V1D You have 2k rep, you are welcome to start retagging some of them

Comment: @Deduplicator Maybe the tag should be 'specific-post' instead of 'specific-question'? That way, it works for questions, answers, or even comments.

Comment: @durron597: I'm surely willing to start but quite afraid by the amount of work to do. So I wanted to know if there were some way to work it around first :)

Comment: Unfortunately, some things cannot be automated. At least yet. And you can get copy-editor and excavator, yeeha!

Comment: @Deduplicator: Right, I guess it was still asking about it on meta though. I'm willing to start doing the work but I think there won't enough of me to do the whole thing. Do you think this thread could be the start of some of us that would tag these questions whilst awaiting for some kind of accepted feature request to handle future ones?

Comment: Well, I try to correct those I stumble over. That must be enough.

Comment: @D4V1D You've got to start somewhere. The [legal burnination](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/295117/1768232) was much bigger than this but we got it done. [source code burnination is progressing nicely](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/298903/1768232). It gets done one question at a time :) Crowdsourcing helps. Feel free to visit the [SO Close Vote Reviewers](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) chat room to help out.

Comment: @durron597: Right, thanks for these infos. I'll then start involving myself in this task waiting for it to be handled by the community if willing to.

Comment: @durron597: Do you have any idea on how I could ping moderators to this post in order to know if a feature could be implemented to handle future MSO questions?

Comment: mods don't decide that, SE does. Also, they sift through [bug] and [feature-request] for inspiration. And always remember that your proposed change must have a higher ROI than whatever else they could work on.

Comment: @Deduplicator: Right, I guess there surely some other priorities on the way. Tyding MSO up with these tags might be less important than focusing on SO itself. Besides, I'm not sure how the ROI could be high on this feature request.

Comment: @D4V1D you ping SE staff by making MSO/MSE questions and then hoping they see them and agree with you. That's about it.

Comment: @durron597: Right, I hope they'll come across this one then :)

Comment: @D4V1D Well, despite not having tons of votes, this seems to have made the "hot meta posts" list, so maybe it will get some more attention.