# Have this tag return to the [source]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request, clean-up

- [source-code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/source-code) is [already gone. Good Job guys!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/298903/1768232)
- [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code) has been blacklisted [since 2011](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/86702/200235)

I think now it's time to do the same thing for [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/source) (1,824 questions). The [SO Close Vote Reviewers](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) chatroom is on the case. Let's get rid of it!

[image: Team Fortress 2 Explosion]

Comment: But then where will Neo have to return to!?

Comment: How should I tag question about parsing source code?

Comment: @Pshemo [tag:parsing]

Comment: OK, just needed to check if this tag still exists and wasn't casualty of other burnations :)

Comment: @Pshemo "use tags that describe what is *essential,* not incitendal to your question", how you plan to parse source code? A static analyzer tool? Some other tool? What language are you trying to parse? etc. are better terms to be added to a tag.

Comment: @Braiam That quote is actually very good point. Thanks for sharing :)

Comment: What about the [source engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_(game_engine))?

Comment: @MorganThrapp That's why I chose this particular explosion image :) A quick search shows there are almost no questions about it that are tagged [tag:source].

Comment: @durron597 I thought that explosion looked familiar. Okay, I wasn't sure. Is there another tag for the engine? Eg, [tag:source-engine] or something?

Comment: @MorganThrapp A search for "[tag:source] engine" didn't turn up much, stuff about seach engines, and only 17 questions. a search for "[tag:source] valve" only turned up 1 question.

Comment: Huh, alright. Then, yeah, this is a silly tag and should be burninated with extreme prejudice.

Comment: ENTIRE TAG IS BABIES!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

All right, so this seems pretty popular. **There are currently <del>1824</del> 0 questions tagged [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/source)**

JUST when you thought it was over... [sources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sources) pops its ugly head up. It's a plural synonym for source, so same rules apply.

#### Editing Status

[sources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sources) 43 questions.

- [Close vote review queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=source+sources)

**[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/source)Editing is done.** Though [watch out for new questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsource%5D+closed%3A0), and you are always welcome to salvage anything you can, even if we already gave up on it.

Just make sure it's actually salvaged and not just lost.

#### Closing Status

**Closing is done.** Though keep an eye out for [new and reopened questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsource%5D+closed%3A0) until everything is gone.

**All questions are closed or edited!**

#### Roomba Status

Questions which need downvotes to be [Roomba-eligible](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006):

- No answers, vote to [0 (closed)](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bsource%5d%20or%20%5bsources%5d%20score%3A1..%20answers%3A0%20closed%3A1%20locked%3A0%20duplicate%3A0), respectively [-1 (open)](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bsource%5d%20or%20%5bsources%5d%20score%3a0..%20answers%3a0%20closed%3a0%20locked%3a0) (only downvote if they deserve deletion, salvage them with a good edit otherwise)
- 1 or more answers, not accepted, vote to 0 [closed](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bsource%5d%20or%20%5bsources%5d%20answers%3A1..%20closed%3A1%20hasaccepted%3A0%20locked%3A0%20score%3A..5%20duplicate%3A0)

#### Deletion Status

These lists are to help identify questions requiring delete votes:

- [Questions that are closed and have an accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsource%5D+or+%5Bsources%5D+closed%3Ayes+hasaccepted%3Ayes)
- [Questions that are closed & Roomba-eligible, but need too many downvotes](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsource%5D+or+%5Bsources%5D+closed%3Ayes+hasaccepted%3Ano+duplicate%3Ano+votes%3A6) on the question. If it's just the question that needs more than 5 downvotes, downvote away. Otherwise, delete-votes are needed to delete these.

**Note:** Any closed questions that have some residual value should just be edited, and have the [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/source) tag removed.

#### Locked Status

These questions require a moderator to burn. However, there are none at this time (this is a placeholder section).